# VFTF for both legs for Indian passport with Australian PR

Tags: singapore, vftf

I am going to travel from Sydney to
India via Singapore and will travel back to Sydney in another 20 days. Both the legs have 23 hours layover and so I want go outside the airport. I was planning to use the VFTF facility. I have Indian passport and Australian Permanent residence. This goindigo link says I can use VFTF on only one leg. But The ICA website doesn't mention about this at all. Has anyone used this for both legs? [httpss://www.goindigo.in/information/vftf-terms-and-conditions.html](https://www.goindigo.in/information/vftf-terms-and-conditions.html)

Update: I was allowed to use VFTF on both ways. The indigo website information is wrong

Comment: Thanks for following up and sharing the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one leg applies only if you are having a Single entry visa. Since you have a PR (multiple entries), this does not apply to you. You can utilize the VFTF for both ways.

ICA website is the official reference for Singapore immigration purposes. Information provided in that trumps any other site.